# jQuery UI Resizable Simple Fixed Footer?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a simple footer that I want fixed to the bottom of the browser.  I want to be able to resize it vertically only.  The problem I have is that once I apply jQuery UI Re-sizable it sets the position to relative which obviously messes up the original intent of the layout.

Below is a simple example using JSBin of my problem.

http://jsbin.com/ubuhic/

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know, in Chrome it looks quite alright

Comment: it should be fixed to the bottom of the browser.

Comment: .... EDIT: just add `!important` to `position: fixed` in you `footer` CSS. I added the answer with complete CSS...

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function () {

    $('footer').resizable({
     handles: 'n, s'
    }).bind('resize', function(){
      $(this).css("top", "auto");
    });

});
```

This code works perfectly for me. http://jsbin.com/ubuhic/11

Answer (score -1):

```
footer
{
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #cc0000;
}
```

`!important` should do the trick...

Comment: looks to be getting closer, but as soon as i start resize it jumps on me again.  are you seeing that behavior?

Comment: this does not entirely fix the issue